How to unit test a custom ErrorStateMatcher in Angular?
I have a custom matcher, very basic, and I don't know how to write a unit test for this (minimum coverage is mandatory on the project).
Should I mock completely FormControl and Form to test each value of submitted/invalid/dirty/touched?
That looks like a lot of mocking, is there anything in Angular to ease that kind of test?
/**
 * Error when invalid control is dirty, touched, or submitted.
 */
export class ShowOnChangeErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    if (!control) {
      return false;
    }

    const isSubmitted = form?.submitted ?? false;
    return control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted);
  }
}


To me it looks quite straightforward to test this. Create an instance of your error state matcher, and call the isErrorState() function with different combinations of control and form according to what you want to test. I don't see the need of Angular providing something to ease up the testability. To "mock" a form control, simply use new FormControl(), same for form group. You can put it into a different state by using spyOnProperty() or by calling functions like markAsTouched().

Here is what I did thanks to comments
describe('ShowOnChangeErrorStateMatcher', () => {
  let errorMatcher: ShowOnChangeErrorStateMatcher;
  let control: FormControl;

  beforeEach(() => {
    errorMatcher = new ShowOnChangeErrorStateMatcher();
    control = new FormControl('1234', Validators.pattern(/^\d*$/));
  });

  describe('isErrorState', () => {
    it('should return false when control is null', () => {
      expect(errorMatcher.isErrorState(null, {} as any)).toBe(false);
    });
    it('should return false when control is invalid but not dirty/touched', () => {
      expect(errorMatcher.isErrorState(new FormControl('1234a',
               Validators.pattern(/^\d*$/)), {} as any)).toBe(false);
    });
    it('should return false when control is valid and dirty', () => {
      control.markAsDirty();
      expect(errorMatcher.isErrorState(control, {} as any)).toBe(false);
    });
    it('should return true when control is invalid and dirty', () => {
      control.setValue('1234a');
      control.markAsDirty();
      expect(errorMatcher.isErrorState(control, {} as any)).toBe(true);
    });
  });
});

